# Rails code to create event on calender , attach map send RSVP email using icalender

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create multiple event on same calender and send invitation of these events to people, so that they can reply to Yes,No,Maybe
(need RSVP button)
and it should display address on google map

here is my code

```
ical = Icalendar::Calendar.new    
#ical.custom_property("X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN", "TRUE")    
ical.timezone.tzid = "UTC"    
email_one = 'example@gmail.com'    
e = Icalendar::Event.new    

e.dtstart = DateTime.civil(2015, 8, 4, 8, 30)    
e.dtend = DateTime.civil(2015, 8, 4, 9, 30)     
e.organizer = %W(mailto:#{email_one})    
e.uid = "111"    
ve.location ="my location"    
#e.RECURRENCE-ID()    
ical.append_custom_property("METHOD", "REQUEST")    

   e.summary = "Please Confirm Meeting"    

   ical.add_event(e)    
   ical.publish    
   ical.to_ical    


attendee_params = { "CUTYPE"   => "INDIVIDUAL",    
                "ROLE"     => "REQ-PARTICIPANT",    
                "PARTSTAT" => "NEEDS-ACTION",    
                "RSVP"     => "TRUE",    
                "CN"       => "Firstname Lastname",    
                "X-NUM-GUESTS" => "1" }    


attendee_value = Icalendar::Values::Text.new("MAILTO:example@example.com", attendee_params)    
ical.append_custom_property("ATTENDEE", attendee_value)    


mail.attachments['appointment.ics'] = { mime_type: 'application/ics', content: ical.to_ical }    
mail(:to => email_one, :subject => "hello" , :from => "example@gmail.com")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot your question, didn't you?

Comment: No, I want to implement this thing.. I am not getting proper syntax to get RSVP button in email